# FA2 showing as a Token and not NFT on TzKT

Tags: nft, fa2, tzkt

I am trying to develop an NFT based on the FA2 standard, but as of now, it is recognized as a Token and not as a NFT inside the balance tab:
https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1Q2FhhCmYq6X1mF6w831EEJnpm6miYnbZH/operations/

Is there a part of the specification / token_metadata to change in order to make it show up correctly ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You store token metadata in a non-standard format, so generic indexers, like TzKT, just cannot parse it (you can see that your metadata wasn't recognized: [ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1..nbZH/tokens/0/metadata](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1Q2FhhCmYq6X1mF6w831EEJnpm6miYnbZH/tokens/0/metadata)).

According to [TZIP-12](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md#token-metadata), token metadata must be stored in the following format:

> Store the values in a big-map annotated `%token_metadata` of type
> `(big_map nat (pair (nat %token_id) (map %token_info string bytes)))`

This will enable indexers to properly parse the metadata.

So, [this is](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1Q2FhhCmYq6X1mF6w831EEJnpm6miYnbZH/storage/390749) how your token metadata looks, and [this is](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1GzUwX2sk3ujk9mxR4BTVBmspApUG4TpTF/storage/390775) how it should look according to the standard.